# Unstable query behavior in windowing function in PostgreSQL 9.6

Tags: sql, postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis

I downloaded OSM data for my country from geofabrik.de, successfully imported it to PostgreSQL 9.6 installed on Ubuntu 16.04 and used it for several times. I also created web application, which works correctly. So I decided to add another functionality which returns top nearest special points (e.g. restaurants) from some points. For one nearest point it works, but when I want return array of them, it doesn't work. So I decomposed my problem and found strange behavior. When I executed following query:

```
SELECT t.osm_id
      FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.points) a.points, v.osm_id AS osm_id, MIN(ST_DISTANCE(v.the_geom, a.points)) OVER (PARTITION BY a.points ORDER BY ST_DISTANCE(v.the_geom, a.points))
        FROM (SELECT ST_GEOMFROMEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(17.104854583740238 48.15099866770469)') AS points) a
        CROSS JOIN ways_vertices_pgr v
      ) AS t
```

it returns:

```
| osm_id            |
| ----------------- |
| 2338524511        |
```

When I displayed this point on map, it is placed far away from original point and after I changed point in subquery, the result remains same. Also I know there are many points between displayed and original point, which should be returned by query. Then I tried run following query:

```
SELECT t.*, t.osm_id
      FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.points) a.points, v.osm_id AS osm_id, MIN(ST_DISTANCE(v.the_geom, a.points)) OVER (PARTITION BY a.points ORDER BY ST_DISTANCE(v.the_geom, a.points))
        FROM (SELECT ST_GEOMFROMEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(17.104854583740238 48.15099866770469)') AS points) a
        CROSS JOIN ways_vertices_pgr v
      ) AS t
```

and it returns:

```
| points                                             | osm_id   | min                  | osm_id     |
| -------------------------------------------------- | -------- | -------------------- | --------   |
| 0101000020E6100000010000C0D71A3140FFC3A1EC53134840 | 33169309 | 0.000124886435658481 | 33169309   |
```

Whole query except SELECT part remains same, but result is different and now it is correct. Can anyone suggest me how to change query to works properly?

Comment: What is the purpose of this `CROSS JOIN ways_vertices_pgr v` Do you really want a carthesian product, or is it a one-row *scalar* table?

Comment: Because subselect can possibly contains several points, not only this one. But behavior is strange for both cases.

Comment: Why don't you join using st_within(), or st_distance() ? #strangebehaviour

Comment: Point of this question is why result of 'SELECT t.osm_id' is completely different from 'SELECT t.*, t.osm_id'. And st_distance will do the same thing, won't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `distinct on`, you need an `order by`.  I think this is the logic you want for the first query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.points) a.points, v.osm_id AS osm_id,ST_DISTANCE(v.the_geom, a.points) as dist
    FROM (SELECT ST_GEOMFROMEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(17.104854583740238 48.15099866770469)') AS points) a CROSS JOIN
         ways_vertices_pgr v
    ORDER BY a.points, dist;
```

Comment: Yes this works perfectly when relation is 1 to N (N nearest points to one specific point). But when relation is M to N (N nearest points to M specific points) I need to use windowing function ordered by distance between two points.

Comment: You wouldn't use `distinct on` if you wanted more than one point.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I think. After @jeremy-schneider 's answer I understand what you really meant by your answer. Now I think 'DISTINCT ON' is useless and I should use only 'MIN' as window function with order you mentioned. I will try it next days and write result here.

Comment: I tried your query and it works! Thank you! I thought the order is given by window function, but you are right, order in which are lines processed in DISTINCT ON is given by ORDER BY clause and MIN window function is totally useless

Answer (score 2):

Check the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` with your query to see exactly why the results are changing when you add the columns.  Likely it's using a slightly different execution plan which affects the ordering of rows.

`DISTINCT ON` is by definition non-deterministic, meaning the results can change between executions.  From [the PostgreSQL 9.6 manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-DISTINCT):

> `SELECT DISTINCT ON` ... Note that the "first row" of a set is unpredictable unless the query is sorted on enough columns to guarantee a unique ordering of the rows arriving at the DISTINCT filter. (DISTINCT ON processing occurs after ORDER BY sorting.)

Adding an `ORDER BY` as Gordon suggested should give you repeatable results.

Comment: I checked execution plans and they differ, so I sorted query as @gordon-linoff suggest and it works. Thank you for your answer, after that I understood what he really meant by his suggestion.